# Why would code performance be better in VSCode?

Tags: c++, performance, g++

I use g++ 12.2.0 (MinGW-w64 via MSYS2) and experience odd performance behavior when running the same code from VSCode (with Code Runner extension) and from the command line. For both, the command used is `g++ f1.cpp -o f1 && f1`.

For example purposes, given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string.h>

using 
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
std::chrono::duration_cast,
std::chrono::nanoseconds;

void timeit(void (*func)(std::string), std::string message){
    auto time_start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    func(message);
    auto time_end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(time_end - time_start).count();
    std::cout << "Execution Time: " << duration * 1e-6f << " [ms]" << std::endl;
}

void run(std::string message){
    std::cout << message.c_str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        timeit(&run, std::to_string(i));
}
```

**VSCode Output:**

> ...
>
> 96
> Execution Time: 0.0025 [ms]
> 97
> Execution Time: 0.0022 [ms]
> 98
> Execution Time: 0.0034 [ms]
> 99
> Execution Time: 0.0029 [ms]

**Command Line Output:**

> ...
>
> 96
> Execution Time: 0.5091 [ms]
> 97
> Execution Time: 0.5168 [ms]
> 98
> Execution Time: 2.4943 [ms]
> 99
> Execution Time: 0.7385 [ms]

The performance is significantly different as seen above.
It is also consistent on PowerShell and even the VSCode terminal itself.

I searched Stack Overflow and other sources for the best of my capability and yet left clueless.

**Edit 1:** I already tried running it with optimizations and up to 1e6 iterations and the issue still persists.

**Edit 2:** [teapot418](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21105992/teapot418)'s answer was precise. It really was limited by the performance of the terminal and replacing `std::endl` with `\n` made a big difference in performance. Replacing the print operation with a different (and even more computationally heavy) operation showed equal performance. [Colonel Thirty Two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646619/colonel-thirty-two)'s answer raised an important point too which I should have clarified beforehand. Issue solved.

Comment: Searched for what? Are you asking "Why is Visual Studio's compiler better than GCC for this particular code?"

Comment: 100 iterations for a microbenchmark is very low. Also ensure you are compiling with optimizations on, as it's pointless to measure performance without them.

Comment: With this code you're probably mostly timing the performance of the terminal/console window. You can also try replacing `std::endl` with `"\n"` as there is a flush hiding in there (which maybe the faster window did not implement?).

Comment: @teapot418 Issue solved. Your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 3):

You are benchmarking the time of your `run` function, which is a single std::cout statement. Measuring I/O times of a single output line is going to have a lot of variance and depend on where stdout is getting routed to.

My psychic powers suggest that VSCode is re-routing stdout to its own output window which has a lot more buffering and performance than the default console window. And I'm guessing your console window is running under some sort of bash/unix emulation on Windows. (Or is this Linux?)

Some things to try:

- You can try increasing the buffer size of the Windows console (or the console app you are using to host mingw)

[image]

- Redirect to /dev/null or nul: on Windows. (e.g. `f1 > /dev/null` or `f1 > nul:`). Of course, you won't see the output, but you could change your `Execution Time` statement to be sent to `cerr` while `cout` is still used in the run function. But then again, I'm not sure what you are measuring.
- Try compiling with -O2 optimizations. That might nullify the difference.
- Try running your compiled program in a default console window instead of the Bash/Mingw/Cygin thing it might be running in now.  You could try running it in powershell too.